# EF Core dont full reference between models

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

My entities classes that are used in the project:

```
    public class Game
    {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int FirstTeamId { get; set; }
    public Team FirstTeam { get; set; }
    public int SecondTeamId { get; set; }
    public Team SecondTeam { get; set; }

    public Stadium Stadium { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public GameStatus Result { get; set; }

    public Game(DateTime date , GameStatus result )
    {
        Date = date;
        Result = result;
    }
}

public class Player
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public PlayerStatus Status { get; set; }
    public PlayerHealthStatus HealthStatus { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public Team Team { get; set; }

    public Player(string name , string surname, DateTime birthday, PlayerStatus status, PlayerHealthStatus healthStatus, int salary)
    {
        Name = name;
        Surname = surname;
        Birthday = birthday;
        Status = status;
        HealthStatus = healthStatus;
        Salary = salary;
    }

}

public class Stadium
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Capacity { get; set; }
    public int PriceForPlace { get; set; }

    public Stadium(string name, int capacity, int priceForPlace)
    {
        Name = name;
        Capacity = capacity;
        PriceForPlace = priceForPlace;
    }
}

public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Player> Players { get; set; }

    public List<Game> Games { get; set; }

    public Team(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public Team(string name, List<Player> players) : this(name)
    {
        Players = players;

    }
}
```

My EF Core context class:

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Game> Games { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Stadium> Stadiums { get; set; }

    public ApplicationContext()
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=best-komp;Database=FootballApplicationDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Player>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Team)
            .WithMany(t => t.Players)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.TeamId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction)
            .HasPrincipalKey(t => t.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Team>()
            .HasMany(t => t.Players)
            .WithOne(p => p.Team)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.Id).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction)
            .HasPrincipalKey(t => t.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Game>()
            .HasOne(g => g.HomeTeam)
            .WithMany(t => t.HomeGames)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.HomeTeamId)
            .HasPrincipalKey(t => t.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Game>()
            .HasOne(g => g.AwayTeam)
            .WithMany(t => t.AwayGames)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.AwayTeamId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction)
            .HasPrincipalKey(t => t.Id);
    }
}
```

But when I try to call my context class, like

```
var db = new ApplicationContext();
```

I can see that my team and player classes dont refer to each other.
All other classes have refer to team, like player have a team, game have a team. But my team classes dont have refer to any class, they have NULL instead a reference.
What is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried use include on your query? Like: db.Teams.Include(t => t.Players)

Comment: @LuttiCoelho dont work:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Team configuration is incorrect. The foreign key should be TeamId not Id. As the FK on Players entity is TeamId.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Team>()
        .HasMany(t => t.Players)
        .WithOne(p => p.Team)
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.TeamId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction)
        .HasPrincipalKey(t => t.Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using ForeignKey annotations. First, add using statement:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
```

Then add a `[ForeignKey("ModelName")]` annotation above each foreign key. For example:

```
[ForeignKey("FirstTeam")]
public int FirstTeamId { get; set; }
public Team FirstTeam { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("SecondTeam")]
public int SecondTeamId { get; set; }
public Team SecondTeam { get; set; }
```

This makes foreign key relationships explicit that EF sometimes can't infer.

Comment: It didn’t help me:(

Comment: See @Lutti Coelho's answer, I think there is an error defining keys in your OnModelCreating override